# PHP Excel remove blank rows at top

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am using PHP to export data from a grid view to an Excel spreadsheet.  For some reason, there are blank rows at the top.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the headers begin printing at row 9, and of course the data starts to print afterward, that which I did not show.

My code works and does what I need it to do.  I am just trying to figure out why it is printing blank rows at the top.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
   $ts = date('mdY-His');
   session_start();
   $where = $_SESSION['where'];  // this is the parameters passed from another file

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE " . $where . " ORDER BY CON_STATUS;";
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("<script language='javascript'>
                                       window.alert('There was no data to send')
                                       window.location.href='../home.php'
                                       </script>");
   header("Content-Type: application/xls");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=importdetails-".$ts.".xls");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

   $sep = "\t";
   for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
   {
     echo mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "\t";
   }
   print("\n");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
   {
     $schema_insert = "";
     for($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); $j++)
     {
       if(!isset($row[$j]))
         $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
       elseif ($row[$j] != "")
         $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
       else
         $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
     }
     $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
     $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
     $schema_insert .= "\t";
     print(trim($schema_insert));
     print "\n";
   }
 ?>
```

As stated, my code works, besides the printing of the blank rows at the top of the spreadsheet.  If you see anything in my code that will remove the blank rows, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions - they are deprecated. Secondly, may I suggest: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ -- It will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Probably print "\n"; this bit is adding the blank rows.

Comment: Regarding this row:  for($j-0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); $j++) -- There is an error in setting the initial value of $j, '-' should be '='

Comment: Regarding this line: for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($results); $i++) -- There is an error in the spelling of '$results' should be '$result'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it looks to me like a problem with your line

```
for($j-0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); $j++)
```

Noting that you are not setting  `$j=0`, but subtracting `0` from `$j`

Comment: Sorry.  That was a typo.  Fixing it now.